# Ruby Sockets: Error (EINVAL) while trying to bind a sending socket to a port

Tags: ruby, sockets, tcp, ip

The `connect` method fails giving an `EINVAL` when I am trying to connect from `blue.example.edu` to `green.example.edu`

I do not get this error when I connect from `blue` to `blue` itself.

The Ruby [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.8.7/libdoc/socket/rdoc/Socket.html#method-i-connect) under `connect` suggests

> Errno::EINVAL - the address length used for the sockaddr is not a
>   valid length for the address family or there is an invalid family in
>   sockaddr

But since the same parameter is working correctly when I try connecting blue to another port on itself, this might be wrong ?

Here is the code snippet:

```
MY_NAME = Socket.gethostname
SERVER_NAME = "blue"    # Socket.gethostname returns 'blue' on the server
SERVER_IP = Socket::getaddrinfo(SERVER_NAME, 'www', nil, Socket::SOCK_STREAM)[0][3]  
#--> Gives me A.B.C.27 (see note on ipconfig below)

SERVER_LISTENING_PORT = 34900

MY_NAME = Socket.gethostname
MY_PORT_FOR_REQUESTING_SERVER = 40000

# other stuff

#CREATE
client_socket = Socket::new(Socket::AF_INET, Socket::SOCK_STREAM, 0)
client_socket_addr = Socket.pack_sockaddr_in(MY_PORT_FOR_REQUESTING_SERVER, MY_NAME)

#BIND
client_socket.bind(client_socket_addr)

#CONNECT
server_addr = Socket.pack_sockaddr_in(SERVER_LISTENING_PORT, SERVER_NAME)
i_tried_with_ip_address_also = Socket.pack_sockaddr_in(SERVER_LISTENING_PORT, SERVER_IP)

#The line below raises the error
client_socket.connect(server_addr)

# more code below
```

Please note that hitting `ifconfig` on blue yields the same `A.B.C.27` what the `SERVER_IP` contains

Under `eth1 - inet addr:A.B.C.27, Bcast:A.B.C.255  Mask:255.255.255.0`

I'm guessing this is related to the issue ?

Using **Ruby 1.8.7** on **Ubuntu** machines

Please advice.

---

### EDIT:

I used TCPSocket as suggested by zed_0xff in order to get this working temporarily.
However I wish to know why the regular socket way is not working.

The only difference I can see is that using the Socket class, I am binding the `client_socket_addr` to a port from which I wish to send my data.
TCPSocket sends data from a random port to the specified listening port on the server.
What do I do if I wish to bind the sending to a specific port ?

---

### EDIT2: Changed question title from:

### Ruby Sockets: Errno::EINVAL: Invalid argument - connect(2)

So the answer from @zed_0xff has helped me tackle one of my problems of actually establishing a connection between the client and the server (Thank you!)

However, with that method, TCPSocket chooses a random sending port for sending data. Trying to binding the sending port to a particular port number fails.

---

*PS: Please let me know if modifying the question name is against the community guidelines. Since my issue was only partially resolved, I edited the title it here itself and explained the edits in the "Edit" sections.*

Comment: Do you try this in a loop? If so: `MY_PORT_FOR_REQUESTING_SERVER` might still be in use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting `EINVAL` for `bind()` indicates that the address to bind to might still be in use.

To get around this

- either use a different address (ip-address and/or port)
- or if you are wanting to reuse a address, set the socket option `SO_REUSEADDR` on the socket prior to using it
- or do not bind ... ;-)

Answer (score 2):

maybe you should try with TCPSocket instead?

```
require 'socket'

s = TCPSocket.new SERVER_NAME, SERVER_LISTENING_PORT

while line = s.gets # Read lines from socket
  puts line         # and print them
end

s.close             # close socket when done
```

http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/socket/rdoc/TCPSocket.html

Comment: Thanks for your response zed_0xff. Using the TCPSocket works. 
But any idea why the lower level Socket class does not work ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the following in my specs:

```rb
url = "http://image.generator.example.com/100x100"
URI.parse(url).open
```

I was getting this error because the image placeholder generator had ceased working. Replacing the URL fixed things.